# Pipelines: cannot publish a file from artifacts directory

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have this pipeline file where I create an `exe` file from an Electron app. At the end of it I'm publishing a Github release with the resulted file (that's what I'm trying at least). The problem is that the `exe` file is not found when doing the release.

```
-   job: Release
    dependsOn:
        - WindowsBuild
    pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
        -   bash:
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=GIT_TAG]$(git describe --tags --always)"
            displayName: "Set the tag name"

        -   task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            inputs:
                artifact: 'Windows'
                path: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

        -   bash:
                ls -la '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            displayName: "List artifacts dir"

        -   task: GitHubRelease@1
            displayName: "Github release"
            inputs:
                gitHubConnection: 'github connection'
                repositoryName: '$(Build.Repository.Name)'
                assets: |
                    '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app.exe'
                action: 'edit'
                target: '$(Build.SourceVersion)'
                tagSource: gitTag
                tag: '$(GIT_TAG)'
                addChangeLog: true
                assetUploadMode: replace
                changeLogCompareToRelease: lastNonDraftRelease
                title: 'Release $(GIT_TAG)'
```

As you can see, one of the tasks I execute is `ls -la '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'` so I can see what's in the `ArtifactStagingDirectory`:

```
Starting: List artifacts dir
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.159.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
ls -la '/home/vsts/work/1/a'
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/4a24644d-728f-4a2a-a7d9-12a5de01f75d.sh
total 70480
drwxr-xr-x 2 vsts docker     4096 Jan 25 17:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 vsts docker     4096 Jan 25 17:14 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 vsts docker 72161249 Jan 25 17:15 app.exe

Finishing: List artifacts dir
```

The `app.exe` file is present. The very next task is `GitHubRelease` which has the specified asset as `'$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app.exe'` which....is not found:

```
Starting: Github release
==============================================================================
Task         : GitHub Release
Description  : Create, edit, or delete a GitHub release
Version      : 1.160.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/AA5vv5o
==============================================================================
b1a3412a-0bb2-48a8-8dfc-bc2109012f38 exists true
Computing changes made in this release...
Fetching the latest non-draft release...
Found the latest non-draft release
Fetching the list of commits since the last published release...
Found the list of changes.
Changes computed successfully.
Release notes file: /home/vsts/work/1/s is a directory and not a file.
Fetching the release for tag: v0.0.28
##[warning]No existing release was found to edit. Creating one with the tag: v0.0.28
Creating a release for tag: v0.0.28
Uploading assets...
Searching for file(s) matching ''/home/vsts/work/1/a/app.exe''.
No files found matching ''/home/vsts/work/1/a/app.exe''. Nothing to upload.
All assets uploaded successfully.
Release created successfully at https://github.com/app/desktop/releases/tag/v0.0.28
Finishing: Github release
```

Any ideas as to what am I doing wrong here>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and remove the single quotes from this line in the YAML

```
assets: |
         '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app.exe'
```

It looks like it is getting interpreted with a duplicate single quotes.

```
Uploading assets...
Searching for file(s) matching ''/home/vsts/work/1/a/app.exe''
```

I have seen this on other Azure DevOps tasks when you use a | for the multi line format.